# (comics library) Convert multiple rar files to multiple cbr files

Tags: convert, zip, calibre, rar

I'd like to convert my comic library to CBR to use in Calibre/ACBF Viewer/Mcomix and Android devices, but I dont want to do a single cbr file.
Is there a faster way to do this?

I use KDE and Unity environments.

Comment: I think this needs more information. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I have a lot of comics, each one on rar files. I wanna convert these rar files to cbr files. I know how to convert one rar file (simple changing to cbr on the file properties), but this way I need a lot of work to convert the entire library.
Example: **batman1.rar, batman2.rar,... batman60.rar**
I wanna convert to **batman1.cbr, batman2.cbr... batman60.cbr**

Comment: The Calibre app should have a bulk convert feature. I use it for managing my ebooks.

Comment: Yes, it have. But just for texts formats (epub, mobi, txt, odt...), however caliber can read comics formats like cbr, cbz and cb7.

Comment: It can convert too.

Comment: Lol, it has. It already add rar into cbr. Thanks

Comment: Added an answer for this. please approve it

Answer (score 0):

Using calibre, you can convert your `.rar` files to `.cbr` files. There is a bulk convert feature that allows multiple conversion of files.